# Python try except block runs the except code when I don't expect a problem and just gives an error when I expect it to run the except code

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot in python that will wish people a happy birthday. I plan on having users give their birthdays to the bot via a command so that it can store it in a txt file. This is the code so far:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def birthday(ctx,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4):
    try:
        if (ctx.user == bot.user):
            return
        print(arg1 + ', ' + str(arg2) + ', ' + str(arg3) + ', ' + str(arg4))
    except:
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send('Oops! I didn\'t get that. Please try again using this format:\n!birthday Garfield 19 6 1978')
```

Basically, it should print the info it got if it is formatted correctly, and warn the user that there's a problem if it is not. This is the error message I get:

```
Ignoring exception in command birthday:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/valerie/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/valerie/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/valerie/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 751, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/valerie/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 670, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/valerie/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 516, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: arg4 is a required argument that is missing.
```

Why is it throwing an exception when everything should work fine and not even running the except code when there actually is a problem? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try removing the try and except blocks and let it fail... the issue might be caused due to something else... and this is the way you can see what is causing it...

Comment: You're using bare `except`, so what's happening is that *some other error* besides the one you expect is occurring but since you're catching everything, you have no idea what it is. Catch only the specific exception(s) you want to handle so you'll get an error message for other ones. Then you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Discord itself is failing to call your function, due to the wrong number of parameters.  Nothing *in* your function is the least bit relevant, because it never actually got executed.

Comment: +1 for @jasonharper. Note the error says arg4 is required and missing. Print it out and you may see why it is failing. It may be None.  Also +1 for kindall, when you do get this to run, you will catch all errors, and you won't know what they are. The arg4 problem may be a 'Type' error.  Use 'Try: something     Except as e:' then print(e)

Comment: @Yatin I tried that and part of the problem was that I had ctx.user instead of ctx.author. Now it works if there are no errors

Comment: Tip: when you want to temporarily disable exception handling, don't comment out the `try` and `except` because then you have to un-indent what was in them, and put it back when you take the comments out. Instead, put `raise` as the first line of the `except` block to re-raise the exception immediately, which has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are calling birthday function which is expecting 5 arguments. You are not providing the required number of arguments. That's why the code is failing.

If you read through the last line of the exception, you will see the error clearly called out.

`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: arg4 is a required argument that is missing.`

You need to provide `arg4` which you are not providing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general comment, but a little too big to fit in the comments...
(so please ignore as you see fit)

You can group you args, and use `", ".join()` to make your code a bit cleaner:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def birthday(ctx, *args):
    try:
        if (ctx.user == bot.user):
            return
        print(", ".join(args))
    except:
        ...
```